# Creating recurring alarms that don't disable easily

Tags: iphone, siri, reminders

I know this is a bit strange. I'm not an Apple user myself, but as a counselor I have many clients who are. Many of my clients have reported the same issue which has become an obstacle to therapy.

I have them set recurring alarms for a daily task or exercise so they are reminded to do them. Sometimes, the alarm itself is part of the exercise (eg., when the alarm goes off, immediately stop the task, switch to a different one, then switch back a few minutes later). But the biggest issue we've run into is clients at some point telling Siri to "turn off all alarms", which inadvertently disables the important one as well and then they forget all about it.

I'm guessing they say this command because they have a day off or something and want all their regular alarms/reminders stopped. But, then they don't remember to reset it, or they just make new alarms for the next day.

Any suggestions to prevent this? Telling Siri to just turn off all TODAY'S alarms? Setting a special alarm that won't go off when Siri turns off all alarms?

Comment: Have you thought about disabling Siri?